# i have a small problem with sorting a list of objects by date

Tags: java, android

so i have a database that has a payment entity within it, the payment entity has few parameters, the most important one is the date parameter, the problem that am facing is am trying to sort the list of payments in the database into a list of lists, each mini list contains the payments made on the same day, [here is an image so you can better understand what am trying to explain.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2V2F.png)

i don't know how do i go about this whatsoever so am just looking for some guidance on how i should approach this.

i don't think that any code is needed here but here is the code to the payment class, and am more than happy to provide more code if it's needed :

```
public class Payment {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@ColumnInfo(name = "id_payment")
int paymentID;
@Embedded
SubjectTeacherCrossRef subjectTeacherCrossRef;
@ColumnInfo(name = "payment_date")
String paymentDate;
@ColumnInfo(name = "payment_total")
int paymentTotal;

public void setPaymentID(int paymentID) {
    this.paymentID = paymentID;
}

public Payment(SubjectTeacherCrossRef subjectTeacherCrossRef, String paymentDate, int paymentTotal) {
    this.subjectTeacherCrossRef = subjectTeacherCrossRef;
    this.paymentDate = paymentDate;
    this.paymentTotal = paymentTotal;
}

public int getPaymentID() {
    return paymentID;
}

public SubjectTeacherCrossRef getSubjectTeacherCrossRef() {
    return subjectTeacherCrossRef;
}

public String getPaymentDate() {
    return paymentDate;
}

public int getPaymentTotal() {
    return paymentTotal;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate on all `Payment` fetched from DB.

Get the `paymentDate` from each `Payment` and store it in a `Map<Date, List<Payment>>`.

Comment: if i iterate on all payments i will get all the dates in there (there is a good chance there will be some duplicates) so how do i make sure i only get one instance of each date, because otherwise i will end up having some duplicates

Answer (score 0):

You must first check in the map if a value (`List<Payment>`) already exists for given key (the date). If not, you must first create the `List<Payment>` instance and put it in the map put(the_date, the_list).

Se method `addPayment(Payment payment)` below.

Remark: you should use a `java.util.Date` object to represent a date rather than a `String`

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class PaymentMap {

private Map<String, List<Payment>> map;

public PaymentMap() {
    super();
    map = new HashMap<String, List<Payment>>();
    System.out.println("map created");
}

public void addPayment(Payment payment) {
    List<Payment> payments;
    String paymentDate = payment.getPaymentDate();
    if ((payments = map.get(paymentDate)) == null) {
        payments = new ArrayList<Payment>();
        map.put(paymentDate, payments);
    }
    payments.add(payment);
    System.out.println("Payment " + payment + " added");
}

public void printMapContent() {
    System.out.println("Map content : " + 
    Arrays.toString(map.entrySet().toArray()));
}

class Payment {
    private int paymentID;
    private SubjectTeacherCrossRef subjectTeacherCrossRef;
    private String paymentDate;
    private int paymentTotal;

    public Payment(SubjectTeacherCrossRef subjectTeacherCrossRef, String paymentDate, int paymentTotal) {
        this.subjectTeacherCrossRef = subjectTeacherCrossRef;
        this.paymentDate = paymentDate;
        this.paymentTotal = paymentTotal;
    }

    public int getPaymentID() {
        return paymentID;
    }

    public SubjectTeacherCrossRef getSubjectTeacherCrossRef() {
        return subjectTeacherCrossRef;
    }

    public String getPaymentDate() {
        return paymentDate;
    }

    public int getPaymentTotal() {
        return paymentTotal;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder("Payment :: date: "+paymentDate+ " - total : "+paymentTotal).toString();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PaymentMap map = new PaymentMap();

    // Adding 3 payments on date 1
    String date1 = "20220128";
    map.addPayment(map.new Payment(null, date1, 1234));
    map.addPayment(map.new Payment(null, date1, 2345));
    map.addPayment(map.new Payment(null, date1, 3456));

    // Adding 2 payments on date 2
    String date2 = "20221125";
    map.addPayment(map.new Payment(null, date2, 4567));
    map.addPayment(map.new Payment(null, date2, 5678));

    // Adding 2 payments on date 3
    String date3 = "20221202";
    map.addPayment(map.new Payment(null, date3, 6789));
    map.addPayment(map.new Payment(null, date3, 7890));

    // Printing map content
    map.printMapContent();
}
}
```